# Arrange four nine and two symbol to make total of $100$?

Tags: puzzle, number-systems

Can you arrange four $9$'s and use of at most $2$ math symbols , make the total be $100$? 
Is this really possible? If it is possible can you help me out?

Comment: How about $$99+9/9  $$

Comment: Thank you.!! this one better.!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple one.

The answer is,

99/.99 =100

this symbols equals to 99/0.99 we can also represent is as 99/.99. Both equals the same.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a correct solution because $.99=\frac{99}{100}$.

Comment: Good answer. Thank you!!!

Comment: @AJ Stas We could consider this anyway, we are taking the result of 99/100 and we are not taking the expression as whole.

Comment: @AJStas Looks like a perfectly good solution to me. Would you not consider lab bhattacharjee's comment as a good answer because $99 = 99.04 - .04$?

Comment: @GammaFunction Since I like being pedantic and playing devil's advocate, $.99$ is not proper notation. The correct notation in $0.99$ which includes the digit $0$.

Comment: @AJStas What about $\frac{99}{99\%}$? Slight change in notation that is widely accepted to be valid.

Comment: @AJstas use the notation .99 in calculator, it accepts, then why can't you?

Answer (score 3):

A just-for-fun solution (with no mathematical symbols!):

$\begin{matrix}
N &  &   & N &   &  &  & N & \\
I &  & I &   & N &  & N &  & I\\
N &  & N &   & I &  & E &  & N\\
E &  &   & E &   &  &  & E & 
\end{matrix}$

Answer (score 1):

$99.99\ldots$

Wait... Is "$\ldots$" one symbol or three symbols?

$99.9\dot{9}$ or $99.\overline{99}$ then.

Comment: You can always replace the "..." by the unicode character U+2026 (horizontal ellipsis) which is a single symbol.

Comment: Well I already typed the "$\ldots$" as \ldots, so that is probably one single symbol.